# What should I do with this error in c++?

Tags: c++

I'm a beginner in c++ and I have this code for a simple calculator, but it had some errors.

1. This error: [Warning] converting to `int' from`float' 
   in line 68 (copy= operand1).
2. and this one: In function `int main()':

How can I fix these errors?
Beforehand thanks for your help;

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

struct Node{
    float number;
    Node *next;
};

Node* push(Node *stack, float data){
  Node *utility;
  utility = new Node;
  utility -> number = data;
  utility -> next = stack;
  return utility;
}

Node* pop(Node *stack, float &data){
  Node *temp;
  if (stack != NULL){
    temp = stack;
    data = stack -> number;
    stack = stack -> next;
    delete temp;
  }
  else cout << "\nERROR: Empty stack.\n";
  return stack;
}

int main()
{
  float answer=0.f, operand1=0.f, operand2=0.f;
  char ch = ' ';
  int neg=0,cont=0,copy;
  Node *utility, *top;

  utility = new Node;
  utility -> number = 0.f;
  utility -> next = NULL;
  top = new Node;
  top -> number = 0.f;
  top -> next = utility;

  cout << "Enter the postfix operation: ";
 while(ch != '\n')
    {
        cin >> noskipws >> ch;
        cont++;    
        if(cont<4&&ch=='-'){
                neg=-1;
                ch=' ';
        }
        int operand = 0;
        while(ch == ' '){
          cin >> ch;
        }      
        if((ch >= '0')&&(ch <= '9')){
          while(ch != ' '){
            operand = operand*10 + (ch-48);
            cin >> ch;
            if(neg==-1 && operand1>=0 ){
                operand=operand * neg;
            }
          }
          neg=0;
          top = push(top, operand);
        }else{
          ****copy=operand1;****
          top=pop(top, operand1);
          top=pop(top, operand2);
          if(operand2<0&&copy>0){
              operand2*=-1;
              if(cont>4)
                  operand2*=-1;
          }
          switch(ch){
            case '+': answer = operand2 + operand1;break;
            case '-': answer = operand2 - operand1;break;
            case '*': answer = operand2 * operand1;break;
            case '/': answer = operand2 / operand1;break;
          }
          top=push(top, answer);
        }
    }
  pop(top, answer);
  cout << "Answer: " << answer << endl;
  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Change `copy` to be a `float` instead of an `int`. Also it'd be better to declare it where it is being used, i.e. on the marked line `float copy = operand1;`

Comment: When posting question about errors or warnings, please include the complete and *unedited* error/warning log. Please edit your question to include it. And also indicate *where* in the source the problems are. You should also try to make a [*Minimal*, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), because the irrelevant code is just in the way.

Comment: You don't have an error. You have a single warning. The first "error" you listed is the warning itself, and the second is information about that warning.

Comment: I usually avoid multiple variable declarations in one statement. Using one statement per variable, and declaring close to where they are used gives a bit more oversight in general IMHO.

Comment: Thank you so much. Actually I tried to change the type of "copy" to float. but I had this one: [Error] expected `,' or `;' before numeric constant. What should I do exactly? I'm really confused.

Answer (score 0):

The offending line is line 68, this is the output of GCC 4.9.0:

E:\test.cpp: In function 'int main()':

E:\test.cpp:68:15: error: invalid type argument of **unary '*'** (have 'int') ****copy=operand1;****

E:\test.cpp:68:31: error: no match for 'operator*' (operand type is 'Node') ****copy=operand1;****

The error indicate that unitary operator * could not be applied to int (there is no unitary operator * for int, only binary)

Line 68: ****copy=operand1;****

The four * in the line at the begining and at the end are the problem, removed.